# including custom filter in angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, browserify, angular-filters

I want to use some custom filter to remove spaces from some url-specific texts in an html of my angular app, i thought i could just create a filter file and require this from the main "angular-app.js".

First of all I have created a new js: filters.browser.js consisting of only:

```
angular.module('customFilters', []).
filter('nospace', function () {
  return function (value) {
    return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/ /g, '');
  };
});
```

I want to be able to use this file so I added
'customFilters' to the app module injection, below is my full "angular-app.js":

```
/* jslint node: true */
'use strict';
var di = require('di');
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-resource');
require('angular-route');
require('bootstrap');
require('angular-bootstrap');

var app = angular.module('developdavid', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngResource',
    'customFilters'
    ]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  //$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : '/home'});
});

var uiModules = {
  angular   : [ 'value', angular ],
  app       : [ 'value', app ]
};
uiModules.uiModules = [ 'value', uiModules ];

var injector = new di.Injector([uiModules]);

/* modules browserify */
```

My partial.jade file that wants to use the filter contains:

```
      a(href='/#/readPost/{{post.title | nospace}}') More
```

Using this setup however I get an "uncaught object" error in the developer console.

Do I need to add more stuff to filters.js?

I want to separate the filters from the rest of the code base.

Also my seed has the following file: browser-requires.js consisting:

```
/* jslint node: true */
'use strict';
var fs            = require('fs');

module.exports = function () {
  var requires = [];
  fs.readdirSync('./sections/').forEach(function (file) {
    var fullpath    = './sections/' + file,
        isDirectory = fs.lstatSync(fullpath).isDirectory();
    if (isDirectory && file !== '_default') {
      var dir = file;
      fs.readdirSync('./sections/' + dir).forEach(function (file) {
        if (/.*\.browser.js$/.test(file)) {
          requires.push('injector.invoke(require(\'../' + dir + '/' + file + '\'));');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return requires.join('');
};
```

Maybe I need to add something to the grunt file to include filters.js in the minified js?

```
/* jslint node: true */
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  var transformify = require('transformify');
  var requires = require('./sections/_default/browser-requires.js')();


  var addRequires = transformify(function (x) {
    return x.replace('/* modules browserify */', requires);
  });
    // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg     : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint  : {
      all     : [ 'Gruntfile.js', 'index.js', 'sections/**/*.js' ]
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'static/js/app.js': ['sections/_default/angular-app.js']
        },
        options: {
          transform: [ addRequires, 'browserify-shim']
        }
      }
    },
    uglify  : {
      target : {
        files : { 'static/js/app.min.js' : 'static/js/app.js' }
      },
      options: {
        mangle: false
      }
    },
    clean : [ 'static/js/app.js' ]
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');


    // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'jshint',
      'browserify',
      'uglify',
      'clean'
    ]
  );

};
```

Comment: Have you written custom filter before this? Or its a fist attempt?